# Cube seems to go in reverse direction as in script in Unity3D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a Cube and the Main Camera as its child. I have attached a script on the cube with the following statement in Update():

```
transform.Translate(Vector3.Normalize(Camera.main.transform.forward) * speed);
```

speed=0 initially and increases with every frame.

This should move the cube in forward direction of the Camera facing. This works fine when initial rotation of both cube and Camera are (0,0,0) and (0,0,0) respectively. Also it works fine if Camera rotates by (0,180,0) keeping cube at (0,0,0) rotation. But if cube is rotated by (0,180,0), the cube and hence the camera moves in reverse direction.

I even tried this:

```
transform.Translate(Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, Camera.main.transform.forward, speed));
```

But with same results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't specify it explicitely, translation is assumed to be relative to object space. Here yo u probably want to move the cube using Camera direction in world space. Try the following:

```
transform.Translate(Camera.main.transform.forward * speed, Space.World);
```